# Simple automount USB devices with fstab: is it normal behaviour?

Tags: mount, usb, fstab, daemon

I notice that adding this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1    /media    vfat   nofail   0   0
```

**will automount any SD card** of my USB SD reader, and **even auto-remount** if I remove the card, and insert a new one.

It is exactly what I need, *it looks like a perfect automount*, not needing any third party tool like `usbmount`, nor `autofs`, nor `udisks`, nor `ldm`, etc.

#### Questions:

1) Is it normal behaviour that this happens?

2) Which hidden process/daemon is looking at `/etc/fstab` continuously and automatically mounts devices when they are inserted?

3) Is it related to `systemd` ?

*Note: I have not added any `udev` rule that does this for me automatically.*

Comment: That must be one of the many tools bundled with systemd